# Tor -> Tor help with orbot

Tags: configuration, help, orbot

I use briar as a messenger and also use orbot system wide with vpn mode switched on. I was wondering if this created tor over tor scenario?

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the under-the-hood configuration of the tools you've mentioned. It can happen, yes. But it's not the only way how it can be working.

Comment: I have orbot configured stock, would a way around this be to select every application besides briar on the VPN allow list on orbot?

Comment: yes, it's one of the right ways for sure

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I seen on orbot github https://github.com/guardianproject/orbot/pull/514/files#diff-dc3d67097da06f21477c01db5570ed182b371cbcc5f0b6d9ba80e2bf72a177a2R16 it has been hardcoded into the application. But it still shows up on the whitelist below, for example for browser dosent show on the VPN list in orbot.